# Building lib from makefile using Qtcreator

Tags: c++, makefile, qt-creator, qmake

I have a lib that I found online, I want to add it to my project as library to include in my Qt-project.

The problem is that the lib needs to be built before it produces the header and the *.a file that I need for this. I can manually add the project and build it before including it to the project using QT-creator, and this ofcourse works.

My question is, can I somehow get qt to build the library as part of the qt-creator build process, so that I can get rid of the manual build step?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Projects->Build Settings and add you Custom Build Steps. At Custom Build Steps you can add your sequence for build

Comment: Thanks! But I found another solution that was more portable!